# Read filenames and extract the initials from it

Tags: batch-file

I have files named as ###.happy.txt, ###_money.txt, ###wealthy.txt and so on. here ### stands for numbers.

I want to extract these numbers and sort these files in my output.

I have solutions in python and shell but batch is very tricky for me.

Comment: What was wrong with any of the solutions given to you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544708/extract-leading-numbers-from-a-string-in-batch-script?

Comment: @SomethingDark - Now the OP wants to sort numerically, so it is definitely a different question. But one that has been asked by others many times, so still a duplicate. For example - http://stackoverflow.com/q/18748744/1012053

Comment: solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748744/read-files-in-directory-in-order-of-filename-prefix-with-batch indeed helped me. Question can be closed. thanks guys.